# Looping query correctly to group by user in spreadsheet/excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm currently trying to fix this script to create a spreadsheet with formulas based on the current data coming from a mySql query. The query is getting excatly what it should and I finally got my loops to print the rows correctly.

Here's an image of what that looks like:
[image]

I'm having trouble of converting this to create the formulas I need. Basically, I need to do a mean, median and mode of the numbers in the 4 main columns at C, D, E and F.

I believe this would need to be done with an index in an associative array but I'm not positive. As seen in the image, column B is the user ID, so I need to group by that.
Basically, saying `If this is the last record for User ID 48, then create a cell for =average(), =Mean() and =median()` and continue for other users. Before the next user
starts, I want to have a cell for mean, median and mode for the 4 columns (C,D,E and F).

I had this array and while loop previously but I couldn't get it to iterate and it continued to print the same record:

```
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            echo "Connected successfully";

            $sql = "
            select 
             concat(u.first_name, '  ', u.last_name) as Name,
             t.ext_id as ID,
             t.total_talk_time_minutes as TalkTime,
             t.total_outbound as Outbound,
             t.total_inbound as Inbound,
             t.dealers_contacted as Dealers,
             t.date_of_report as Date
            From
                ambition.ambition_totals t
            INNER JOIN
                ambition.ambition_users u
            ON 
                t.extension = u.extension
            where
                date_of_report 
            between
                curdate() - interval 5 day and curdate()"  or die(mysqli_error( $conn));

            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('A') -> setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('B') -> setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('C') -> setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('D') -> setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('E') -> setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('F') -> setAutoSize(true);
            $sheet ->getColumnDimension('G') -> setAutoSize(true);

            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Name');
            $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'User ID');
            $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Talk Time Per Call');
            $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Outbound Calls');
            $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Inbound Calls');
            $sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'Dealer Contacts');
            $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Date');


            $data = [];

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if (!isset($data[$row['ID']]))
                    $data[$row['ID']] = ['records' => [], 'mmm' => []];
                $data[$row['ID']]['records'] = $row;
            }

            $analyze = ['TalkTime', 'Outbound', 'Inbound', 'Dealers'];

             foreach ($data AS $user) {
                 foreach ($analyze AS $attr) {
                     $set = []; 
                     foreach ($user['records'] AS $record){
                        $set[] = $record[$attr];
                        $user['mmm'][$attr] = [];
                        $user['mmm'][$attr]['mean'] = calcMean($set);
                        $user['mmm'][$attr]['median'] = calcMedian($set);
                        $user['mmm'][$attr]['mode'] = calcMode($set);
                    }
                }
            }

            var_dump($record);


            mysqli_close($conn);

            $writer = new xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $writer->save('Coaching Report - Weekly.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect an array of users containing the data and analysis is the best way to go.

```
$data = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // New user? Build data structure
    if (!isset($data[$row['ID']]))
        $data[$row['ID']] = ['records' => [], 'mmm' => []];
    // Collect rows
    $data[$row['ID']]['records'][] = $row;
}
```

And then iterate over user entries in order to calculate the mean, median, and mode (mmm):

```
$analyze = ['TalkTime', 'Outbound', 'Inbound', 'Dealers'];
foreach ($data AS &$user) {
    foreach ($analyze AS $attr) {
        $set = []; // Set of data for this attribute
        foreach ($user['records'] AS $record)
            $set[] = $record[$attr];
        $user['mmm'][$attr] = [];
        $user['mmm'][$attr]['mean'] = calcMean($set);
        $user['mmm'][$attr]['median'] = calcMedian($set);
        $user['mmm'][$attr]['mode'] = calcMode($set);
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of deciding how you want to output the data on your sheet.

Comment: I think I understand this after looking at it a bit more. Basically, with this I can continue to do what I'm doing now but I would replace my while and foreach with yours? And then I would just setCellValues per attribute?

Comment: Essentially. You'll still need to output to the sheet, but this is how you can structure your data in memory

Comment: Ok, so I am trying to work this into my script right now. I'm currently getting an illegal string offset error on the line with ``` $set[] = $record[$attr];``` and an undefined variable for calcMean but that's just because I haven't defined that with a formula yet

Comment: var_dump record and make sure it contains the row from the database, and ensure that the aliases used there match up with the strings from the $analyze array

Comment: Ok I fixed the loop issue because it was missing a bracket, so now it's looping properly but giving an illegal string offset for all 4 variables in 'analyze'. The var_dump seems to just be dumping the date stringg

Comment: Sounds like something is going wrong where you're building $data. Can't offer a lot of help without seeing your code

Comment: I'm not sure. I edited my code above to reflect basically everything I have. My original array in the example built just fine but I feel like something in the extra 'analyze' feature here isn't lining up. I just can't tell from the dump what it is. I'll keep playing with it

Comment: However, $data seems to dump fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164640/discussion-between-sorak-and-tom-n).

Comment: Apologies @sorak, I have one more quick question: Since each user may have up to 5 records in this query result, could I add date to the record ID rather than just their ID? Because if they have 5 records all with the same user ID it's only going to select one of those